# R Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Tags: r

The code in which I am getting the error.

```
numCrimesByLSOA<-crimes %>%
  select(LSOA.code, LSOA.name, Crime.type) %>%
  group_by(LSOA.code) %>%
  summarise(Num.crimes=n())
```

Comment: You probably have the wrong `summarise` ... did you load `plyr` too?  Try `dplyr::summarise()` and/or `find("summarise")`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this as **@BenBolker** suggested:

```
#Code
numCrimesByLSOA<-crimes %>%
  dplyr::select(LSOA.code, LSOA.name, Crime.type) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(LSOA.code) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Num.crimes=n())
```